# Get string from two rows

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

Want to convert output to variables, from the first row want to take every time the last result.

```
There are 1 server(s) in cluster: SQL_GDM
MS_SQL_sql1.local.com---RUNNING
There are 2 server(s) in cluster: MONGO_GDM
MS_MONGO1_mongo1.local.com---RUNNING
MS_MONGO2_mongo2.local.com---RUNNING
```

Expected view:

```
SQL_GDM|sql1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo2.local.com|RUNNING
```

For now I just take only the state of the servers with:

```
grep -oP '(?<=---)\w+'
```

I'm wondering how to remove MS_*_ and to stay only the host and after that to grep the state of the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
$ awk '/^There/{a=$(NF-1)"_"$NF;next}{print a,$3,$NF}' FS='[ _-]' OFS='|' file
SQL_GDM|sql1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo2.local.com|RUNNING
```

**Explanation:**

- `FS='[ _-]'` separate each record into fields using spaces, underscores and hyphens as field separators.
- `OFS='|'` separate the output fields using the pipe symbol.
- `/^There/{a=$(NF-1)"_"$NF;next}` If the line starts with `There` store the last two fields separated by an underscore in the variable `a` and grab the next line.
- `{print a,$3,$NF}` for lines that don't start `There` print the value of `a`, the third field and last field.

Comment: Perfect and simple, could you explain me please!?

Comment: @KalinBorisov added a short explanation.

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate the result for example:
RUNNING can make to lowerscape, where is need to put guess [A-Z] [a-z] or related to this column string.

Comment: `awk` has the function `tolower()` so you would just do `{print a,$3,tolower($NF)}`

Comment: Thank you @sudo_O I just find it and see you comment :)

Answer (score 5):

One way with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). It uses a regular expression to split fields, one or more hyphens (`-+`) or a colon followed by optional spaces characters (`:[[:space:]]*`). That way is easier to find either the cluster and the state. For the server I split with `_` and extract last path.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
        FS = "-+|:[[:space:]]*"
}

$0 ~ /:/ {
        cluster = $NF
        next
}

{
        n = split( $1, server, /_/ )
        printf "%s|%s|%s\n", cluster, server[ n ], $NF
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

And it yields:

```
SQL_GDM|sql1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo2.local.com|RUNNING
```

Answer (score 4):

you can remove the MS_*_ by piping the output through sed

```
echo "MS_MONGO1_mongo1.local.com---RUNNING" |  sed "s/^MS_.*_//"
```

or create an awk script `convert.awk`

```
/cluster:/{ cluster = $NF; }
/^MS_/{ 
  gsub("---","|"); 
  gsub("^MS_.*_",""); 
  printf("%s|%s\n",  cluster,$0); 
}
```

and pipe your output through

```
awk -f convert.awk
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -lne 'if(/cluster: ([\S]*)/){$a=$1}elsif(/_.*_(.*?)---(.*)/){print "$a|$1|$2"}' your_file
```

Tested below

```
> cat temp
There are 1 server(s) in cluster: SQL_GDM
MS_SQL_sql1.local.com---RUNNING
There are 2 server(s) in cluster: MONGO_GDM
MS_MONGO1_mongo1.local.com---RUNNING
MS_MONGO2_mongo2.local.com---RUNNING
> perl -lne 'if(/cluster: ([\S]*)/){$a=$1}elsif(/_.*_(.*?)---(.*)/){print "$a|$1|$2"}' temp
SQL_GDM|sql1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo1.local.com|RUNNING
MONGO_GDM|mongo2.local.com|RUNNING
```

Answer (score 2):

Toy example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputFile = shift(@ARGV);
open (my $input, $inputFile);

my $cluster = undef;

  while(<$input>)
  {
    chomp;

    if ($_ =~ /^There are \d+ server\(s\) in cluster: (\w+)$/)
    { 
        $cluster = $1; #keeps track of current cluster
    }

    else 
    {
        $_ =~ s/.*_.*_//; #removes the underscores and non-sense associated with them

        if ($_ =~ /---([A-Z]+)/)
        {
            my $temp = $1; #extracts RUNNING or NOT_RUNNING, or what have you

            $_ =~ s/---$temp//; #removes hypens/STATE from $_

            print "$cluster|$_|$temp\n";
        }
    }
  }
```

Comments are in the code.  I assumed that there is one entry per line. If you put your input into a file and open it as `$input`, it will produce the exact output that you desired.  If you need more explanation, leave a comment.